# UIDocumentInteractionController failing to send file via AirDrop

Tags: ios, uidocumentinteraction, airdrop

I am using `UIDocumentInteractionController` to share a KML (Geo XML) file.  When I use the `UIDocumentInteractionController` I can open the KML file in other apps just fine.  I can send it via email.  However, when I try to share it via AirDrop to my mac I get this error message.  I know that AirDrop works between my iPhne and my Mac since I can use it just fine in other apps.  I can actually share the KML from my app to another app and then share the KML file from other apps via AirDrop.

```
Sender kSFOperationEventErrorOccured {  
    Error = "Error Domain=SFOperation Code=-1 \"Transfer failed.  Try again.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Transfer failed.  Try again.}";  
    Files =     (  
                {  
            FileBomPath = "./topoMapsExport.kml";  
            FileIsDirectory = 0;  
            FileName = "topoMapsExport.kml";  
            FileType = "com.trailbehind.kml";  
        }  
    );  
    ReceiverComputerName = "Stephen\U2019s MacBook Pro";  
    ReceiverID = 994fcdc90a7d;  
    ReceiverModelName = "MacBook Pro";  
    SessionID = 3C1A7DF67296;  
    TotalBytes = 11857;  
    UsePKZip = 0;  
    VerifiableIdentity = 0;  
}
```

Does anyone know why sharing via AirDrop would fail?

Here is how I set up the document interaction controller.

```
//Path is the path to my kml file.  The path does exist and it has the correct data in it.  
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];  

    self.documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];  
    self.documentController.UTI = @"com.google.earth.kml";  
    self.documentController.name = @"topoMapsExport.kml";  
    [self.documentController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:self.exportButton.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Did you file a bug report?

Comment: I haven't filed a bug report.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps define `self.documentControler.delegate`?

And add

```
#pragma mark - UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate

- (UIViewController *) documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview: (UIDocumentInteractionController *) controller {
    return self;
}
```